# How can I implement a C# shuffle algorithm in an extension method?

Tags: c#

I have a list that looks like this:

```
IList<TQBase> hs;

public class TQBase
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public int q { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to shuffle this list and I found this method:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

I am trying to use it like this:

```
 IList<TQBase> tqhb // This is populated from the repository in an earlier statement

 var abc = tqhb.Shuffle<TQBase>();
```

It's giving me an error pointing to abc and saying:

```
 Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable
```

Is there a problem with the way I am trying to do the shuffle ?

Comment: `var abc = tqhb.Shuffle<TQBase>();` Shuffle(); returns void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension method shuffles the list inline, you don't have to assign the return to anything (Hence why the return type is `void`!).

```
tqhb.Shuffle<TQBase>();
```

Also, the compiler should be smart enough to figure out the generic type of the method so you should just be able to call

```
tqhb.Shuffle();
```

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way to shuffle:

```
hs.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

For simple shuffling purposes a `Guid` is random enough. Create a `Guid` for each entry and order by it, it will end up as a shuffled list.

I realize it doesn't solve the problem in your extension, but others have already covered it. It seems like you were looking for a shuffle mechanism and not this one in particular so I provided an easy-to-use alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a new variable a value when your extension method returns type `void`. Use it like this:

```
tqhb.Shuffle<TQBase>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your Extension method:

```
public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    } 
    return list; 
}
```

Or, you use it without assignment:

```
tqhb.Shuffle<TQBase>();
```

After tqhb will be different.